# "Improve the Blender Manual" event proposal

Tags: discussion

The [Blender manual](http://blender.org/manual/) still has many rough spots from [it's recent migration from the old wiki](http://blender.org/manual/about/migration.html).
Many pages are severely out of date, incomplete, or missing.

Since we are a community of Blender users who spend time writing about how to use Blender, I thought it would be a good idea to organize an event to contribute en mass to the official manual project.

Having a good manual is not only beneficial to Blender and it's users, but also can directly enhance SE content by providing a consistent and easily-linked reference for answerers and questioners alike — provided it's complete and up to date.

### But wait! I thought the devs were supposed to do this?

Well, yes, developers do write documentation. But a lot of documentation from the old wiki ended up mostly disorganized, not very consistent, and over time became out of date.

To fix this, a [switch was made to Sphinx](http://blender.org/manual/about/migration.html) (the same system used for the python API docs). Hopefully this system will provide a more controlled and organized platform for managing the manual once the docs which were imported from the old wiki are cleaned up. There is are large amounts of still out-of-date and incomplete documentation, and cleaning all of it up is a *monumental* task for only a few people. Developer time is precious, and naturally it's in the interest of blender users to ensure that they have as much time as possible to make blender more awesome ;)

### Alright then, what's the idea?

I suggest putting on a site event for a week and creating a dedicated [chat room](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) where fellow documenters can exchange ideas and ask questions.

Perhaps we could set some kind of goal for the end of the week, e.g. clear 10 tasks from the [to-do list](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/query/LI_sAFnT.BNd/#R).

### I want to start right now! Where do I go?

<s>Well, we aren't starting just yet..</s>

See this [meta post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/859/599) for details!

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to convince a developer/expert to drop by and help anyone who is baffled by some of the confusing technical overhead? Probably unlikely, but it would be cool

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I expect we could get Greg Zaal in on it (he was hired by blender to work on the docs).

Comment: @GiantCowFilms What technicalities in particular?

Comment: @gandalf3 Sphinx setup, svn... committing the entire thing

Comment: @GiantCowFilms For the most part probably I or Greg Zaal can answer such questions. It's when things go wrong that we might need an expert..

Comment: The docs could definitely use your guys' help :) I can help where I can - just poke me in the chat or on irc (pixaal)

Comment: This sounds like a fantastic idea, I'd love to participate!  I also might note that in many cases people who are naturally good at something are very bad at explaining it, so it often isn't a great idea to have devs write manuals.