# Documentation second opinion?

Tags: discussion

Is https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask a good place to get second opinions on changes being made to [documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/contents.html)?

Comment: Also note that part of the reason patches go through a "review" process on phabricator (developer.blender.org) is for exactly this purpose. You'll likely receive some feedback there as well.

Comment: But that is if you are new and submit patches. I have access to push the .diff files myself without external permission. Besides, I have a feeling that the developers have better stuff to worry about than grammer/ minor documentation edits.

Comment: Even with push rights, it can be a good idea to put large/potentially controversial changes through review anyway. Anyone can pitch in with the review process, and there is a special "documentation team" (with a number of non-developers) who look at submitted patches. For smaller stuff of course, a quick question in `#blenderwiki` on IRC or in B.SE chat can't go amiss..
There's also the bf-docboard mailing list, which is useful for calling attention to something or to get an authoritative opinion, e.g. if you have a proposal for drastically changing the structure of the docs or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

BSE and our meta has no connection (aside from whatever users contribute to both) to blender's official docs. Posting a change to blender's doc on the meta here will never make it into a change.

Instead if you found something that needs fixing, just edit it yourself.

Gandalf wrote up a great post on how to get started
[Improving the Blender manual](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/859/2217).

Even if you don't want to go through the whole process to edit the manual yourself you still should not post your changes on the meta here. You can report problems here: https://developer.blender.org/project/board/53/

---

If you just want a quick second opinion to a change (not too large) I would recommend you head over to our site's [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) or more appropriately the [Manual Project](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27326/manual-project) room (the reason I say the renderfarm first is because there is always somebody there); and post your change in there.

Comment: im looking for a place to get feedback for things im changing in the manual. I know how to make the changes, but im not always sure that they are good changes.

Comment: @eromod take a look at my edit

Comment: just what I was looking for, ty

Comment: I would say one of the main places to contact those in charge of documentation is via the [bf-docboard mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-docboard)